# How can I add a gap around the edge of a Jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jython

I want to leave the default border on my `JButton`s, but put empty space around them as well. I'm using a vertical `BoxLayout`.

- I originally said nothing about the borders, and got single pixel `LineBorder`s, which I want, but the buttons all butted up against each other.
- I then tried `button[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5))`. Rather than adding blank space around the button, it made the buttons' areas expand. It also removed the `LineBorder`.
- I then tried: `button[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5), button.getBorder()))`

This gave me back the `LineBorder`, but rather than adding blank space outside the line, it just extended the buttons' areas beyond the line!

I realise I can add blank boxes to space my buttons out, but I want space on the sides of them as well, which is why I want to add an `EmptyBorder`. I'm new to Swing, so maybe there's an entirely better way of doing this that I don't know about :)

I'm using Jython, but the API should be the same as from Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, the "empty borders" you want to add are not really part of the button (for example, they should not be clickable).

This is actually a matter of layout, so you should probably check the documentation of the layout manager you are using. For example:

- Some layout managers, such as [FlowLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html), [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), or [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html), have `hgap` and `vgap` properties to specify the horizontal and vertical gaps between components.
- With [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) you would set the `insets` of a [GridBagConstraints](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) object.
- With [BoxLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) you would add "rigid areas", "glue", and "fillers" (see the [Box](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html) class).

And so on.

Comment: Hmmm. When I click the button outside of the line border, it still works? FlowLayout doesn't let you arrange things vertically does it?

Comment: @CamJackson: FlowLayout does not let you arrange things vertically, but BoxLayout does.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the answer is basically 'Find a better layout!' :P

Comment: Almost :) Actually the answer is: 1/ Do this in the layout manager + 2/ Use the right layout manager.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's simpler to add the button to a panel and set the empty border to the panel.

Comment: This could work too. The border on the panel would then be an empty inside an etched, inside a title, inside an empty (space on the outside of the panel). Am I 'Doing It Wrong' if I have four layers of nesting on my borders?

Comment: Multiple layers is ok. I would even create a custom component MyBorderedButton extends JPanel and use it instead of button where it's necessary.

Comment: @StanislavL: I find it confusing to have a XXXButton subclass which is actually a JPanel (and not a subclass of Button). For example, would attach an action listener to your MyBorderedButton, or to the Button inside?

Comment: You can add such a method and call delegate button's method.

Comment: Of course -- but this was just an example. If you use other JButton functions and features you might end up replicating a large part of the JButton API in the MyBorderedButton class.

Comment: +1 The [`setBorder()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29) API suggests just this approach.